# Oracle SQL - Combining columns with 'OR' bit function

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle 12.2 - I have a table with 3 columns... ID, ParentID and ProductList.  ID is unique, with multiple IDs rolling up to a ParentID.  (this is a account model... basically multiple accounts have the same parent...)  ProductList is a string...also exactly 20 bytes... right now it is 20 letters of 'Y' and 'N', such as YYNYNYNYNNNY... but I can change the 'Y' and 'N' to 1 and 0 if it will help... what I need to do is within a group of ParentID, calculate a bitwise OR of the ProductList.  The end result I need is a 20 byte string (or some type of 20 bits of data)  that says - for each respective letter/bit - if any 'Y' then return 'Y'.  Again, I can use 1/0 if easier than Y/N.

Here is pseudoCode of what I am trying to do...  Any help appreciated.

```
with T1 as
(
select 10 as ID, 20 as ParentID, 'YYNNYNYNYNYYNNYNYNYN' as ProductList from dual
union
select 11 as ID, 20 as ParentID, 'NNNNNNNNNNYYYYYYYYYY' as ProductList from dual
union
select 22 as ID, 20 as ParentID, 'YYNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN' as ProductList from dual
)
SELECT ParentID, BitWiseOr(ProductList) FROM t1
group by ParentID;
```

Comment: "It ain't what you don't know as makes you a fool, it's what you do know that ain't so" (popular saying). You say that "I know Oracle supports a BitWise OR function (designated with a | symbol)". Really? Can you point to the documentation? This is news to me. Oracle only has `BITAND`, which can be used to create your own `BITOR`; other than that, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: You are correct.  I read the docs to quickly.  I found the listing, but the title was for Interactive Reporting, not SQL...  I will update the question.

Comment: It's not clear that BITOR (which you can create easily from BITAND) will be too helpful. It is not difficult to convert strings from Y/N to 1/0 and back; but they will still be strings, while BIT* work on integers. And Oracle has TO_CHAR and TO_NUMBER functions to convert between strings and integers, and you can use those in base 16, but they don't have options to make them work for binary representation, which is what you need. You can write your own functions for all of these, but perhaps the data model itself should be reconsidered first, if possible.

Comment: @mathguy - The model has the tables with one row per ID, then 120 or so columns, each with a 'Y' or 'N'. The string (and this question) is part of a rollup table that is used to count the NUMBER of 'Y' values...I wanted to NOT have to go to the base tables, but I may have too,,,,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the brute force method of taking the maximum of each character and then using `||`:

```
SELECT ParentID, 
       (max(substr(productlist,  1, 1)) ||
        max(substr(productlist,  2, 1)) ||
        max(substr(productlist,  3, 1)) ||
        . . .
        max(substr(productlist, 20, 1)) ||
       )
FROM t1
GROUP BY ParentID;
```

This works because `'Y' > 'N'`.

Note:  This is a lousy data model.  You should have a separate table with one row per `id` and product.

Comment: The model has the tables with one row per ID, then 120 or so columns, each with a 'Y' or 'N'. The string (and this question) is part of a rollup table that is used to count the NUMBER of 'Y' values...I wanted to NOT have to go to the base tables...

Answer (score 0):

You can destruct string to atomic values, compute result of `or` operation and assemble it back into string. (Credit to @GordonLinoff for Y>N trick.)  [dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ba25063a73be407c8c0464dd399fe22b).

Unfortunately, Oracle does not allow something like `unpivot (val FOR substring(ProductList,i,1 in ...` and also Oracle does not have equivalent to Postgres `bool_or`, which would both made solution simpler. At least this solution scales with `ProductList` length.

Anyway you should avoid violating 1st normal form. If you cannot, it IMHO does not matter how boolean is modelled.

```sql
with T1 as
(
select 10 as ID, 20 as ParentID, 'YYNNYNYNYNYYNNYNYNYN' as ProductList from dual
union
select 11 as ID, 20 as ParentID, 'NNNNNNNNNNYYYYYYYYYY' as ProductList from dual
union
select 22 as ID, 20 as ParentID, 'YYNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN' as ProductList from dual
), series (i) as (
  select level as i
  from dual
  connect by level <= 20
), applied_or as (
  select t1.parentid
       , max(substr(t1.productlist, series.i, 1)) as or_result
       , series.i
  from t1
  cross join series
  group by t1.parentid, series.i
)
select parentid
     , listagg(or_result) within group (order by i)
from applied_or
group by parentid
```